# Well ordering principle vs induction proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I was asked to recast an induction proof to a proof by well ordering princple. How are the 2 different? From my understanding the two are equivalent, so how will the proof be different? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Well-Ordering and Mathematical Induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432293/well-ordering-and-mathematical-induction)

Comment: Different statements can be logically equivalent. They are still different.

Comment: Usually if you take a look at a proof by the well ordering principle it usually is used to prove that given a set that has positive integers as elements that it has a least element. Usually done so by contradiction. Take a look at a proof of the division alogrithm. While  induction does imply the well ordering principle and vice versa. But if its going from an induction proof to a proof by the well ordering principle those are two different proof techniques. What was the proof you were trying to change?

Comment: @user60887 I'm trying to proof that "If I draw n straight lines on a piece of paper I cannot divide the piece of paper into more than
n(n+1)/2 +1 regions"

Comment: *Because* they are equivalent, you can transform one into the other.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an induction proof of some statement $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: P(n)$, you presumable have some reasoning that concludes $P(0)$ and other reasoning that proves $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

This can be transformed into a proof using the well-ordering principle as follows:

Suppose that $\lnot \forall  n \in \mathbb{N}: P(n)$. Then there is at least one $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $\lnot P(n)$; take the least such $n$.
By [insert reasoning here that $P(0)$] $n \neq 0$.
By [insert reasoning here that $P(n-1) \implies P(n)$, which we can do because $n \neq 0$] we now also have $\lnot P(n-1)$.
This contradicts the fact that $n$ was minimal.

Therefore $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: P(n)$.

(Note, this looks most natural if you original reasoning for $P(n) \implies P(n+1)$ actually works by assuming $\lnot P(n+1)$ and concluding $\lnot P(n)$.)