# Using the WOP to check divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, well-orders

The well-ordering principle states that every non-empty set of positive integers contains a least element.

I need to prove that 9|$n^3+(n+1)^3+(n+2)^3$ , $n∈N$ using this principle.

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  You could prove it using induction, since $n^3-(n-3)^3=9(n^2-3n+3)$

Comment: [WOP and induction are equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432293/well-ordering-and-mathematical-induction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is false then by WOP there is a *least* counterexample $k$ with $\,9\nmid f_k.\,$ Note $\,k>0\,$ by $\,f_0 = 9.\,$  Note $\bmod 9\!:\ f_{n+1}\!- f_n = (n\!+\!3)^3\!-n^3\equiv 0\,$ so $\,9\mid f_{n+1}\!\!\iff\! 9\mid f_n,\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{9\nmid f_k\Rightarrow 9\nmid f_{k-1}},\,$ so $\,k\!-\!1\ge 0\,$ is a smaller counterexample, contradiction.

**Remark** $ $ It is more natural to use ascent (induction) than $\rm\color{#c00}{descent}$ (WOP). Indeed, the proof shows that,  modulo $9,\,$ the value of $f_n$ never changes $\,f_{n+1}\equiv f_n\,$ so reformulating the above *positively* as an induction proves  that $\,f_n\,$ is a constant sequence $\,f_n \equiv f_0\,$ for all $n\,$ (and here $\,f_0 = 9\equiv 0)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you please explain this step: $(n+3)^3−n^3≡0$ ?

Comment: @The Binomial Theorem $\large \Rightarrow (n\!+\!\color{#c00}{3})^{\large\color{#0a0}3} = 3^{\large 0} n^{\large 3} + \color{#0a0}{3\,\cdot}\,\color{#c00}{ 3^{\large 1}} n^2 + \color{#c00}{3^{\large 2}}\color{}{(\cdots)}\equiv n^{\large 3}\color{#0a0}{\pmod {\!\color{#c00}9}},\ $ i.e. all summands (except first $\large \,= n^3)\,$ have coef's divisible by $\,\color{#c00}9\,$ so they all are $\large\equiv 0\pmod{\!\color{#c00}{9}}\ \ \ $

Comment: Ok, but why would $n^3$ also be divisble by 9  ?

Comment: @The proof does not claim $\, 9\mid  n^3.\ $ Where did that come from?

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood because of the $n^3(mod9)$ and $≡0(mod9)$. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Direct proof:
$$n^3+(n+1)^3+(n+2)^3\equiv  \\
3(n+1)(n^2+2n+3)\equiv \\
6n(n+1)(n+2)+9(n+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{9}.$$
Can you interpret why the first addend is a multiple of $9$?